# How to save query historial in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I need to save the query historial in Hyperledger Fabric, for example if I have a marble Object and I query it 2 times, I would like to retrieve the query historial. I already try call a query with PEER INVOKE and then use GetHistorialForKey function but it does not work because of the asset is not been modify

Comment: you can see this. hope it helps: https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/Channel.html#queryTransaction

Comment: I'm using GoLang I can not find the equivalent function in GoLang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to turn your queries into invokes, which would result in them being subject to the rules of invoke and slowing them down.

Comment: I already tried using a query as invocation but it does not work, can you be clear? can you write some code or references?

Comment: What does your code look like for invoke? If it does not have a PutState somewhere inside of it, it will not work.

The short answer is that what you are asking for does not make much sense in the domain. The ledger has no need to store queries, so it does not. It only stores transactions that write to the chain.

I read your question as "For every read to the chain, do a write to the chain."